# макрос excel выделение и копирование строк

Tags: excel, vba, макрос

Здравствуйте.
Есть лист в экселе, в котором имеется таблица формата

1. имя1
2. имя2

Но количество строк всегда разное. Как можно макросом узнать количество строк, и перенести их на новый лист?
Спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Номер строки самой нижней ячейки, которая использована на листе

```
lRws = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
```

Количество срок можно определить по наличию значений в определенном столбце:

```
With ActiveSheet
    lRws = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

Этими двумя методами можно определить последнюю ячейку, но не всегда. Если последние строки скрыты, они в подсчет не попадут.

Количество строк пользовательского диапазона:

```
lRws = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

Здесь тоже есть небольшой подводный камень. Считаем количество строк в пользовательском диапазоне, т.е. с первой использованной до последней. Но строки не всегда используются с первой. Обходим:

```
With ActiveSheet
    lRws = .UsedRange.Row + .UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1
End With
```

Стоит упомянуть и о "большом подводном камне" при использовании *UsedRange.Row*. Это касается и *SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row* (а вот *.End(xlUp).Row* к этому нечувствителен).

Часто пользователи форматируют строки с запасом. Или на листе данные, копированные с другого диапазона. Или ниже данных скрыты строки... Учитывается весь пользовательский диапазон, все форматированные строки. Даже те строки, которые удалены, но сохранение изменений еще не произведено. И вместо 10 строк будет определено 10000 )

Нужно это все учитывать и применять то, что наиболее подходит к данной задаче.

' ----------------------

С переносом данных тоже не все однозначно. Можно *Вырезать/Вставить*, *Копировать/Вставить*. Если расположение данных разное или нужна фильтрация, лучше пользоваться массивами (обработка в памяти и выгрузка на лист результата).

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы узнать количество строк на листе воспользуйтесь:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

' Соответственно, затем, выделяете область методом   
Range([область вашего диапазона]).Select
' Копируете  
Selection.Copy
' Получаете вашу новую книгу и вставляете
Sheet.Paste
```

Comment: Не спешите ) Проверьте количество строк при скрытии нижних (вручную или автофильтром)